# RSI from Trading View is different from my RSI calculation

Tags: javascript, node.js, finance, algorithmic-trading

I'm making a bot in node.js and I collected historical data + real time data by using binance api and binance websocket, by doing that I can give my bot the most recent data in real time.

I'm trying to calculate the RSI and the values I get are different from Trading View (and binance).

This is my function:

The function accepts 2 parameters, period and table name. Period is the number of candles it should consider in order to make the calculations, `tableName` is where it should get the candles from my db and also the type of candle (1m, 5m, 1h etc...)

`Klines` is an array of candles, they are already sorted from newest to oldest, so `Kline[i]` is new compared to `Kline[i+1]`.

```js
async function calculateRSI(period, tableName) {
    const klines = await getKlines(period, tableName);
    // Calculate percentage changes in price
    const percentageChanges = [];

    for (let i = klines.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const closePricePrev = klines[i - 1].close_price;
        const closePriceCurr = klines[i].close_price;
        const percentageChange = ((closePricePrev - closePriceCurr) / closePricePrev) * 100;
        percentageChanges.push(percentageChange);
    }    

    // Calculate gains and losses
    const gains = [];
    const losses = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < percentageChanges.length; i++) {
        if (percentageChanges[i] >= 0) {
            gains.push(percentageChanges[i]);
            losses.push(0);
        } else {
            gains.push(0);
            losses.push(-percentageChanges[i]);
        }
    }

    const sumGain = gains.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
    const sumLoss = losses.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

    // Calculate Relative Strength (RS)
    const RS = sumGain / sumLoss;

    // Calculate RSI
    const RSI = 100 - (100 / (1 + RS));

    console.log(`RSI:${tableName} ${period}`, RSI);
}
```